# Slowing down 960 fps video with ffmpeg (setpts is not working)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, pts

I am trying to slow down a video recorded on an Android phone at `960fps`. I found a lot of previous posts and blogs that all basically say the same thing, that you need to change the "presentation timestamp" (pts). I also found the [official documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video) that is saying the same thing. The command-line basically looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=4*PTS" -r 30 -y output.mp4
```

I copied the video file using Android Filter Transfer and when I use the above command-line, it works to slow it down, but the resulting output is choppy. The output of the `ffmpeg` also indicates that it is duplicating the frames:

```
frame=  687 fps=103 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4454kB time=00:00:22.80 bitrate=1600.1kbits/s dup=515 drop=0 speed=3.42x
```

Running `ffprobe` on the file shows this:

```
ffprobe version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.1.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-lda
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VID_20161030_213810.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2016-10-30 16:08:14
    location        : +17.3874+078.3395/
    location-eng    : +17.3874+078.3395/
    com.android.version: 6.0.1
    com.android.capture.fps: 120.000000
  Duration: 00:00:05.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14991 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 13859 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-10-30 16:08:14
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
```

This seems to detect that the video is `30 fps` instead of `960 fps`, which is probably why it is filling in with duplicate frames instead of using the existing frames.

I recording the video on Lenovo Z2 Plus (AKA Zuk Z2). If I playback the video using the built-in player at a slow speed it looks extremely smooth, so the frames are definitely there. Could someone help me figure out the right way? The file is available [here](https://app.box.com/s/0gpm0xsn1qkazfshg4zs04djhbon2n9z) (about 10MB), in case someone would like to try it.

Update: Video playback at slo-mo on the phone recorded with another phone. Notice how smooth and slow the sparks are thrown around, which is impossible if the original video is 30fps.

- [Slow-mo clip 1](https://app.box.com/s/xtyd954mo144yksfq9zxxvzguhfp78rn)
- [Slow-mo click 2](https://app.box.com/s/gwplwyrgvmhs9z8fug1bbhn6iteqcy6p)
- [Full video played in slow-mo (47s, probably at 120fps)](https://app.box.com/s/n89pj82aqcy2rz5ew6x28ewlv44dx3qn)

Comment: How long is your uploaded file supposed to be?

Comment: It is about 5.7 seconds.

Comment: It has only 172 frames, so it's not 960 fps, but actually 30 fps.

Comment: @Mulvya How did you check? As I said, Slow-mo playback on the phone is extremely smooth. I added 2 video clips to highlight this fact. I also recorded the full video at slow-mo (also available for download), and the length of the video suggests that the playback was done at 120fps (down from 960fps).

Comment: Which of the new uploads are slo-mo from the Z2P?

Comment: I ran `ffprobe VID_20161030_213810.mp4 -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames` to check frame count.

Comment: Looks like your original video was recorded at 120 fps. See this line above: `com.android.capture.fps: 120.000000`

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks for the useful references. I am thinking that both of those values reported by `ffprobe` are incorrect, as is the `fps` that is reported as `30`. When I played back at max slow-mo on the phone, it took ~47s, which is 8 times the original or 15fps (if 120fps were to be correct), but I feel that the video is too smoother to be just 15fps.

Comment: See this screenshot of the built-in player that indicates that it is 960fps: https://app.box.com/s/z5ib6vc74h0vtwz2p6vdpbkts3rnsfcd

Comment: The 120.0000 figure is stored in the file by the writing app, not generated by ffmpeg, only reported. The 30 tbr is the frame rate stored by the writing app. FFmpeg estimates the fps by dividing total number of frames by duration, so that may be incorrect. But the first two are directly reported.

Comment: Ok. See http://www.hispeedcams.com/lenovo-zuk-z2-960fps-slow-motion-just-interpolation/

Comment: @Mul Thanks for the link, I understand that it is a marketing gimmick. Considering it is 120fps, I still can't get ffmpeg to slow it down to 30fps. The frames are still duped if I use `setpts=4*PTS` :(

Comment: That's because the video is saved as 30fps. I'm not sure if the video is slow motion or 90 of the captured frames per second have been discarded.

Comment: @Mulvya I am copying the file to the laptop using Android File Transfer, so it is the same file that exists on the phone. Also, if I use iMovie to slow it down to 1/4th the speed, I am getting a lot smoother video, but if I increase the PTS by 4 times using ffmpeg, it is quite jerky as it is duping the frames.